# how can I load spark Image control and wait for complete loading

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image, mxml

how can I load in flex spark Image control and wait for complete loading? MX:image have method load() and listen COMPLETE event
this is not in spark Image...is there only source?? or how can i listen when image is complete loading??

thanks for help

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, I know the skin has some states related to this, like "loading" and "ready". You might want to check it out or at least check the change state conditions

Answer (score 0):

In mxml, you can just use the COMPLETE property (Flex 4.5 has it - I don't know about anything previous) on a Spark Image component.

Or just set an event listener, as described [Here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3events/).